# Correct order of operations in neo4j - LOAD, MERGE, MATCH, WITH, SET

Tags: neo4j, nosql, cypher

I am loading simple csv data into neo4j. The data is simple as follows :-

```
uniqueId      compound     value    category
ACT12_M_609   mesulfen      21      carbon
ACT12_M_609   MNAF          23      carbon
ACT12_M_609   nifluridide   20      suphate
ACT12_M_609   sulfur        23      carbon
```

I am loading the data from the URL using the following query -

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM "url"
AS row
MERGE( t: Transaction { transactionId: row.uniqueId })
MERGE(c:Compound {name: row.compound})
MERGE (t)-[r:CONTAINS]->(c) 
ON CREATE SET c.category= row.category
ON CREATE SET r.price =row.value
```

Next I do the aggregation to count total orders for a compound and create property for a node in the following way -

```
MATCH (c:Compound) <-[:CONTAINS]- (t:Transaction)
with c.name as name, count( distinct t.transactionId) as ord
set c.orders = ord
```

So far so good. I can accomplish what I want but I have the following 2 questions -

1. How can I create the `orders` property for `compound` node in the first step itself? .i.e. when I am loading the data I would like to perform the aggregation straight away.
2. For a compound node I am also setting the property for category. Theoretically, it can also be modelled as `category -contains-> compound` by creating `Category`node. But what advantage will I have if I do it? Because I can execute the queries and get the expected output without creating this additional node.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think that's possible, LOAD CSV goes over one row at a time, so at row 1, it doesn't know how many more rows will follow.
   I guess you could create virtual nodes and relationships, aggregate those and then use those to create the real nodes, but that would be way more complicated. [Virtual Nodes/Rels](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/)
2. That depends on the questions/queries you want to ask.
   A graph database is optimised for following relationships, so if you often do a query where the category is a criteria (e.g. `MATCH (c: Category {category_id: 12})-[r]-(:Compound)` ), it might be more performant to create a label for it.
   If you just want to get the category in the results (e.g. `RETURN compound.category`), then it's fine as a property.